# Flutter UI widgets in Unity 3D engine

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, flutter-engine

I am looking for support which can render the flutter widgets inside unity 3d engine.
This will be helpful to utilize in our current flutter application and for building 3D applications.
I am new to flutter it will be helpful if anyone can suggest me how I can achieve this with flutter API or Flutter Engine.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is UIWidgets. Version 2.0 debuts for preview recently.
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.uiwidgets

The sample project looks impressive:
https://github.com/UnityTech/ConnectAppCN

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to render flutter widgets in unity but surely the other way around.

Check out [`flutter_unity_widget`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) which allows you to embed Unity game scenes in flutter.

And this Medium article might be helpful - [Unity 3D in Flutter](https://medium.com/@weird_beird/unity-3d-in-flutter-e842b982d0f)

Comment: Thanks @sidrao2006 for you helpful answer.
Can I know is there any possibility to do so in future with fuller engine inside unity or this is a platform dependent problem?. As I am beginner in Flutter I don't have core understanding for the same. Any of your thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Mmh, I am not so sure if embedding the flutter engine in unity is possible. The flutter engine is mainly written in dart and C language for the platform embedder, its hard to think of a way to put them together. Even if you could, you would have to write your own platform embedder and call these APIs from the engine. You would be better off embedding Unity in flutter even if the other way around is possible

Comment: Thank you so much @sidrao2006 for your thoughts. 
Do you have any suggestions where I can try my possibilities to get flutter app inside unity ?

Comment: @user2335072, not very sure about that